# Convert f-string syntax to print in older versions of python

Tags: python, f-string

How do i convert an f-string in python so that it can be printed by python version older than 3.6?

```
print(f"Player 1: {move1}  Player 2: {move2}")
```

When I try to run this in Python (3.5.3) it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Try `print("Player 1: {move1}  Player 2: {move2}".format(move1=move1, move2=move2))`

Comment: Personally I don't think your question is a duplicate of the one linked. The answer is to use the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method of the built-in `str` class, which will work in both current and past versions (upto the point when _that_ feature was added anyway — which was in Python 2.6).

Answer (score 4):

```
print("Player 1: {move1} Player 2: {move2}".format(move1=move1, move2=move2))
```

will work in most recent versions of python. As will

```
print("Player 1: {}  Player 2: {}".format(move1, move2))
```

and if you want to use the old formatting syntax that'll work in python2 as well:

```
print("Player 1: %s  Player 2: %s" % (move1, move2))
```

Comment: Could also just do `print(f"Player 1: {move1} Player 2: {move2}")`.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse The question is how to replace the f-string with something compatible with earlier versions of Python.

Comment: @chepner I understand but the answer said: "will work in most recent versions of python" so I figured might as well put that there to since `format` is already there (which is for recent python versions).